# Does Airflow support jar file?

Tags: jar, airflow, talend

i am a newbie to Airflow. i have some .jar jobs generated with T**alend Open Studio for Big Data**, and i want to schedule and manage those with Airflow my question is , does Airflow support .jar file or generated by TOS  as **DAG**  ? 
and if it does how  ? 
or is there any alternative to run .jar on Airlow ?

im using Airflow  v1.10.3
the jobs are mainly to extract and process data from a mongodb database then update the database with the new processed data.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow will happily run `.jar` files. There is a few examples kicking about for you to have a look at.

Running a standard `.jar` file: [run_jar.py](https://gist.github.com/isaacmg/c1942b1d43ccabe6a8259b9786dff076)

Running a "built" Talend jobl [loan_application_data.py](https://github.com/treselle-systems/airflow_to_manage_talend_etl_jobs/blob/master/loan_application_data.py)

Obviously with both these examples the `.jar` or Talend file(s) will need to be on the server Airflow is executing on (as well as Java).

Comment: thank you for your answer @Tomme,  when you said they need to be on Airflow server you mean on the .py file needs to be under  `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` ?

Comment: No worries. Yes you will need your DAG file in the `dags` folder, but I also mean the "worker" that is executing the task will need to be able to see the `.jar` file. If you are only running Airflow locally (`LocalExecutor`) then you don't need to worry, but if you plan on executing jobs remotely (`CeleryExecutor`/`KubernetesExecutor`) then this is something you will need to think about.

Comment: I see thank you for the information !  right now i need to be able to execute my dags locally, but i still have some difficulties to import libraries generated by talend to execute my DAG (.jar)

Comment: @Tomme I ve seen your code, can u say how to manage libraries in this case? where should be located?

Answer (score 4):

Airflow does support running jar files. You do this through the `BashOperator`.

Quick example:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys

args = {
  'owner': 'you', 
  'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 24),
  'provide_context': True
}


dag = DAG(
    task_id = 'runjar', 
    schedule_interval = None, #manually triggered 
    default_args = args)

run_jar_task= BashOperator(
  task_id = 'runjar',
  dag = dag,
  bash_command = 'java -cp /path/to/your/jar.jar param1 param2'
  )
```

Comment: But what if the jar file is connecting to a database? It would need a jdbc driver and how can i configure that in airflow?

Comment: @user679530 This may be what you are looking for: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-jdbc/stable/operators.html

Comment: Hi Zack, but this is when if I want to write the code in airflow dag , correct? In my case I have this code written in java already.