# Use Airflow to schedule Spring Batch jobs

Tags: spring, airflow, spring-batch, airflow-2.x

I am trying to schedule Spring Batch jobs on on-prem Kubernetes using Airflow but couldn't find enough documentation.

I am looking for some documentation with steps to follow to schedule a Spring Batch job.

We also have pyspark jobs which also use Airflow and I need to set dependencies between them for triggering.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how you launch your Spring Batch app, but if you package it in an uber-jar and run with with something like `java -jar myjob.jar`, then you can follow the following approach:

[Does Airflow support jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850929/does-airflow-support-jar-file)

The scheduling configuration is defined in this part:

```
dag = DAG(
    task_id = 'runjar', 
    schedule_interval = None, #manually triggered 
    default_args = args)
```